# Saving ImageString (QImage) into MSSQL Database of Bytearray QT

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt, arrays, qimage

## How to Save QImage into MSSQL Database of Bytearray QT

The following code convert my QImage into a string.
I would like to save it into MSSQL with utf-8 (varchar(max)). All other strings works fine with inserting it, but not this.
This is empty in the Database

```
 QByteArray theByteArr;
        QBuffer buffer(&theByteArr);
        theIm->save(&buffer,"PNG");
        QString theBase64Str= QString::fromLatin1(theByteArr.toBase64().data());
        QString theBaseStr=theBase64Str.toUtf8();
```

Comment: C++ Or C# getting confuse

Comment: C++ is the languague i write it

Comment: Your last line is useless. You need to save `toUtf8` result into `QByteArray`, not `QString`

Comment: how you mean it? can you make an example code?